# Earned Reputation Points Rollback for the below scenario

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I wanted ask if there was any case where question or the answer has been up-voted but due to some reason it was deleted therefore because it is not valid a valid answer or a question,so in this case should the earned reputation points have to be rolled-back?

Comment: See [how does reputation work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).  Deleted posts will roll back reputation unless the post has a score of >= 3 and is 60+ days old. So recent, low-voted posts will lose rep when deleted.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks :) and you can add this as the answer so I can vote your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most complete explanation of reputation changes after post deletion is explained in the [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/156833)  post at the network-wide meta.stackexchange.com site.

With regard specifically to upvoted but deleted posts, posts which have been on the site for 60 days and with a score >= 3 will not result in a loss of reputation when the post is deleted.  Any deleted post not meeting those criteria will cause reputation from upvotes to be rolled back.

Like the meta.stackexchange.com answer, I'll also link to [an additional official source of this info at the Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).